# Java - How to populate an array with elements that have been passed as parameters

Tags: java, arrays

I want to populate an array that I have in my method with elements that I receive as parameters to my method. I cannot use any methods from predefined classes such as `Arrays` or `Collections`

Example:

In my main method in my main class I have:

```
ClassB obj = new ClassB obj ();

obj.addElement(objD1);

obj.addElement(objD2);
```

What I expect in my method addElement (B Class):

```
public void addElement(ClassD element){

    ClassD[] array = new ClassD[10];
```

and then how do I populate?

A `for` loop? Two `for` loops?

End result I want:

```
array[0] = objD1;

array[1] = objD2;
```

Comment: I don't understand... your "end result" `array[0] = objD1; array[1] = objD2;` *is* the code you need to populate your array. Please clarify.

Comment: There's something conceptually wrong. Since `ClassD[] array` is declared inside the `addElement()` method, it will be destroyed as soon as the method ends. The two consecutive calls to `addElement` that you show above aren't quite right. The code would have much more sense if `ClassD[] array` was defined **outside** the method.

Comment: yes it will be outside of the class, the problem still stays open to me, how to popu late my array?

Comment: As a side node, your question is not really clear; for this reason you've got downvoted. Please, try to spend more time writing your question, read it twice and help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not really clear. If my understanding is correct you want to define your `ClassB` like:

```java
public class ClassB {
    private ClassD[] array = new ClassD[10];
    private int index;

    public void addElement(ClassB element) {
        array[index++] = element;
    }
}
```

The code you're asking for is probably `array[index++] = element`. Here we insert the `element` inside `array` in position `index` and then we increment `index` (using the post-increment operator `++`).

There are few problems with this implementation, though. First of all you can't add more than 10 elements. Adding the 11th element will result in a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExcepiton`. I would suggest to manage the exception and throw something more descriptive like:

```java
    public void addElement(ClassB element) {
        if (index >= array.length) {
            throw new TooManyElementsException();
        }

        array[index++] = element;
    }
```

Where `TooManyElementsException` is simply defined as:

```java
public class TooManyElementsException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

**EDIT**

Following your comment, I can slightly modify the `addElement()` method and get there.

```java
    public void addElement(ClassB element) {
        int index = 0;

        while (index < array.length && array[index] != null) {
            index++;
        }

        if (index >= array.length) {
            throw new TooManyElementsException();
        }

        array[index] = element;
    }
```

The whole thing works because Java always sets all the elements to `null` when you create a new array. So, every time we start from `0` and we look for the first `null` position; then, we put our `element` there.

Comment: thank u mneri for your answer, in my task I cannot use private int index, I have only  private ClassD[] array = new ClassD[10] as attribute.

Comment: I have a predifined template with exact description of attributes and methods in the class, according to it, my the only attribute is an array, and I cannot use other methods to help me out with addElement method. It seems that population of the array has to happen inside of the addElement method

Comment: Please, check the **EDIT** to my answer and if it solves your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: I get an exception  Index 10 out of bounds for length 10

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I corrected the answer, now.

Comment: Thank u mneri  u answered my quesiton!